# Identify leafy green plant?

Tags: identification

[image: green leafy plant]

Previous owners of the house planted it, and we want to plant more!

I live in hardiness zone 6b. Leaves are ~2 feet high and the plant is growing in a south facing bed, but is under partial shade almost all day. Soil is topsoil under mulch. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a [hosta](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosta). Actually two, one with large dark green leaves and one smaller with lighter leaves.

Hostas are a family of plants that caught the attention of gardeners not for their blooms (which may or may not be showy, I happen to have one with a lovely scent), but for their foliage. Breeders have created cultivars in many shades of green, some variegated, and with various leaf sizes and even texture. What’s also a plus is that hostas prefer dappled shade and thus fill the spots many flowering plants don’t like too much.

If you want more, you can either split your existing plants, or do some research on which cultivar you‘d like to accompany your current collection. Just a little warning - I have seen gardeners go a tiny bit overboard when they got hooked.

Comment: To Stephie's point about gardeners going a bit overboard with hostas, when I worked at a nursery that carried about 100 different varieties of hosta I once rang up a sale of over $400 - all hostas (maybe 20 plants, total). The customer said that that was only part of her "haul" of hostas that day. It can be a pricey hobby (the most expensive hosta that we carried at that time was Kaleidoscope, which sold for about $40 in a 6" pot containing 2, maybe 3 pips.

Comment: https://www.marthastewart.com/920229/martha-visits-gorgeous-hosta-garden Beautiful, though.